# Android loses content when rotate device or re-open APP without logout

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I'm create a items list with CardViews and RecyclerView.

When I rotate, re-open the APP without logout or re-create the activity the content is lost. The content is displayed only when you first create the activity (after Login in APP).

I'm not sure why it may be happening and I wonder if someone could help me out.

I put the code here:

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    ActionBar actionBar;
    TextView textView;
    Intent intent;

    private SQLiteHandler db;
    private SessionManager session;

    private RecyclerView recycler;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager lManager;

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jParser;

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_itemS = "items";
    private static final String TAG_item_ID = "item_id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_USERNAME = "username";
    private static final String TAG_PHOTO = "photo";

    List<item> items;

    JSONArray items = null;

    HashMap<String, String> user;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        items = new ArrayList<>();

        new LoadAllitems().execute();

        recycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);

        lManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recycler.setLayoutManager(lManager);


        adapter = new itemAdapter(items);
        recycler.setAdapter(adapter);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu_white_24dp);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.navigation_drawer_layout);

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

        if (navigationView != null) {
            setupNavigationDrawerContent(navigationView);
            View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.navigation_drawer_header, null);
            TextView navheaduser = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.usernameSession);
            navheaduser.setText("asdfa");
        }

        setupNavigationDrawerContent(navigationView);

        db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        if (!session.isLoggedIn()) {
            logoutUser();
        }

        user = db.getUserDetails();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_allitems, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void setupNavigationDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.item_navigation_drawer_allitems:
                                menuItem.setChecked(true);
                                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                return true;
                            case R.id.item_navigation_drawer_myitems:
                                menuItem.setChecked(true);
                                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Myitems.class);
                                return true;
                            case R.id.item_navigation_drawer_logout:
                                menuItem.setChecked(true);
                                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                                logoutUser();
                                return true;
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                });
    }

    public static Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) {
        try {
            InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
            return d;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void logoutUser() {
        session.setLogin(false);

        db.deleteUsers();

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    class LoadAllitems extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.loadingitems));
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All items from url
         */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            jParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(AppConfig.URL_GET_ALL_itemS, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All items: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // items found
                    // Getting Array of items
                    items = json.getJSONArray(TAG_itemS);

                    // looping through All items
                    for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = items.getJSONObject(i);
                        items.add(new item(c.getInt(TAG_item_ID), getResources().getIdentifier(String.valueOf(LoadImageFromWebOperations(c.getString(TAG_PHOTO))), "drawable", getPackageName()), c.getString(TAG_NAME), c.getString(TAG_USERNAME)));
                    }
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                } else {
                    // no items found
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

itemAdapter.class:

```
public class itemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<itemAdapter.itemViewHolder> {
    private List<item> items;

    public static class itemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView image;
        public TextView name;
        public TextView userName;
        //public TextView description;
        public TextView username;

        public itemViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.itemImage);
            name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
            //userName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.userName);
            //description = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.itemdescription);
            username = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.username);
        }
    }

    public itemAdapter(List items) {

        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public itemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_card, viewGroup, false);
        return new itemViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(itemViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        viewHolder.image.setImageResource(items.get(i).getImagen());
        viewHolder.name.setText(items.get(i).getName());
        viewHolder.username.setText(viewHolder.username.getText() + " " + String.valueOf(items.get(i).getUsernamer()));
    }
}
```

item.class:

```
public class item {
    private int item_id;
    private int image;
    private String name;
    private String username;
    private String description;

    public item(int item_id, int imagen, String name, String username) {
        this.item_id = item_id;
        this.image = imagen;
        this.name = name;
        this.username = username;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getitem_id() {
        return item_id;
    }

    public String getName() {

        return name;
    }

    public String getUsernamer() {

        return username;
    }

    public String getdescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public int getImagen() {

        return image;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="@bool/fitsSystemWindows">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/status_bar_height"
            android:background="?colorPrimary"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/status_bar_height"
            android:background="?colorPrimaryDark"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/status_bar_height">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="@bool/fitsSystemWindows"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer_menu"
        app:theme="@style/NavigationViewTheme" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

item_card.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/itemImage"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:id="@+id/itemName"
            android:textColor="#666"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/itemImage"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/userTag"
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:textColor="#666"
            android:layout_below="@+id/itemName"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/itemName" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#ffd5d5d5"
            android:id="@+id/linea"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/itemImage">

        </View>


    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Can anyone help me? I'm searching and trying for fix it but I can't make it work.

Thanks!!

EDIT:

I added this code and now the list is loader on rotate an re-create the activity, but the list is duplicated adding itself.

```
@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putParcelableArrayList("ITEMS", items);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        items.clear();
        items = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("ITEMS");
        adapter = new itemAdapter(items);
        recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Android recreates the layout everytime you rotate your device. Therefore, if
you want the user to be able to rotate the device (orientation change), you have 
to override the Activity method `onSaveInstanceState` and provide a Bunde
with all your needed information's.

After the orientation is changed, this bundle will be given to you in

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

so you can recreate your views and activity state.

Edit: also do not forget to finish your AsyncTask

Edit: I already added a small explanation what you need to do, but in this
case I think a Google link is valid: [Recreating an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html)

As said, Android will recreate your Activity, everytime you change the orientation of your device. Because the layout needs to reinflate etc..

1. initialize your app in onCreate
2. do your activity logic while the activity is active
3. if the activity goes into background `onSaveInstanceState` is called
4. save ALL your needed information's in the bundle (which is given as an arguement to the method)
5. your activity is recreated
6. fetch your saved information's from the bundle given to onCreate

Comment: I already have protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) in my code. How I can finish my AsyncTask? Thanks!!

Comment: Yes you have the method in your code, but you are not using the bundle. Are you sure you want to support orientation changes? (It's much easier without in the beginning) Anyway, you need to get your variables back from the bundle, which you saved earlier into the bundle in onSaveInstanceState.  I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you! I put the code I added in my first post edit and now list is duplicated on refresh. When I rotate or recreate the activity the list is repeated, adding the list to the last list.

Comment: Did you clear the list in the old adapter and called onDataSetChanged on the list?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the @JacksOnF1re solution or add this in your manifest in the activity that require

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Any additional code is not necessary in your case.

Comment: Santiago is totally right here, but I suggest to read the doc nevertheless @ alexca. "Note: Using this attribute should be avoided and used only as a last resort. Please read Handling Runtime Changes for more information about how to properly handle a restart due to a configuration change."

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

search for android:configChanges

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying to avoid this and use it as a last resort.